# Is there any way to write a LINQ Query,for condition like where IDs is in ('ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4'). in(VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want to write below SQL query using LINQ Query in VB.Net,
Could someone please suggest if there is any way to write it?

```sql
Select Count(Distinct(User_ID)) from tbl_CTRL where Req_ID = "R1" AND User_ID in ('001','002','004','005')
```

TABLE: *tbl_CTRL*

```
 User_ID        Req_ID
   001          R1
   002          R2
   003          R1  
   004          R1
   005          R2
   001          R2
   002          R3
```

Expected Output is:
Count= 2

Comment: You do not mention the name of the variable that stores the rows nor do you mention if the rows are a collection of a custom class, a DataTable, or something else all together.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
    'Assuming you have a DataTable
    'Dim tbl_CTRL As DataTable = New DataTable 
    Dim elCounts As Integer = (From element In tbl_CTRL
                               Where {"001", "002", "004", "005"}.Contains(CStr(element.Field(Of Object)("User_ID")))
                               Select element
                               Distinct).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

The following has not been fully test but should work for what you want. In the example below the WHERE IN condition when dynamically created uses parameters rather than injection in this case a comma delimited list of values for the command.

Full working code sample can be found in the following [GitHub repository](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WindowsFormsTextBoxWhereClause).

Finally **SQL**

```
SELECT C.CustomerIdentifier ,
                   C.CompanyName ,
                   C.ContactName ,
                   C.ContactTypeIdentifier ,
                   FORMAT(C.ModifiedDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy', 'en-US') AS ModifiedDate,
                   CT.ContactTitle
            FROM   dbo.Customers AS C
            INNER JOIN dbo.ContactType AS CT ON C.ContactTypeIdentifier = CT.ContactTypeIdentifier
            WHERE CT.ContactTitle IN (@CTContactTitle0,@CTContactTitle1) AND Req_ID = "R1"
            ORDER BY C.CompanyName
```

Code to create WHERE IN

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

''' <summary>
''' Contains methods to create dynamic WHERE IN conditions on a single field
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>
''' These methods are not meant to handle every single condition, they are
''' for simple IN clauses e.g. 
''' 
''' WHERE SomeField IN (1,2,3)
''' WHERE SomeField IN ('June','April')
''' WHERE YEAR(SomeField) IN (2008,2007,2018)
''' WHERE SomeField IN ('4-4-1960','9-22-1989')
''' 
''' If a function is year that has arguments these methods will not handle
''' them "as is".
''' 
''' </remarks>
Public Module SqlWhereInParameterBuilder
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create a SQL SELECT statement which is then passed off to
    ''' AddParamsToCommand to create a parameter for each value.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <typeparam name="T">SELECT Statement with WHERE condition</typeparam>
    ''' <param name="partialClause">Base SQL SELECT statement</param>
    ''' <param name="paramPrefix">WHERE IN field</param>
    ''' <param name="parameters">Value list for WHERE IN</param>
    ''' <returns>SELECT Statement with WHERE condition ready to populate values</returns>
    Public Function BuildWhereInClause(Of T)(partialClause As String, paramPrefix As String, parameters As IEnumerable(Of T)) As String

        paramPrefix = StripFunction(paramPrefix)

        Dim parameterNames = parameters.Select(
            Function(paramText, paramNumber) $"@{paramPrefix.Replace(".", "")}{paramNumber}").ToArray()

        Dim whereInClause = String.Format(partialClause.Trim(), String.Join(",", parameterNames))

        Return whereInClause

    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create a parameter for each value in parameters
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <typeparam name="T">Command with parameters setup</typeparam>
    ''' <param name="cmd">Command object</param>
    ''' <param name="paramPrefix">Field name for the WHERE IN</param>
    ''' <param name="parameters">Values for the WHERE IN</param>
    <Extension>
    Public Sub AddParamsToCommand(Of T)(cmd As SqlCommand, paramPrefix As String, parameters As IEnumerable(Of T))
        paramPrefix = StripFunction(paramPrefix)

        Dim parameterValues = parameters.Select(Function(paramText) paramText).ToArray()
        Dim parameterNames() As String = parameterValues.Select(
            Function(paramText, paramNumber) $"@{paramPrefix.Replace(".", "")}{paramNumber}").ToArray()

        For index As Integer = 0 To parameterNames.Length - 1
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterNames(index), parameterValues(index))
        Next

        '
        ' Display what a hacker would see
        '
        If Debugger.IsAttached Then
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText)
        End If

    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Used to get a field name from a function e.g. YEAR(ActiveDate)
    ''' which will return ActiveDate.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="pValue"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Private Function StripFunction(pValue As String) As String
        If pValue.Contains("(") Then
            Dim regularExpressionPattern As String = "(?<=\()[^}]*(?=\))"
            Dim re As New Regex(regularExpressionPattern)
            Return re.Matches(pValue)(0).ToString()
        Else
            Return pValue
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Here is a roughed out example in a console project (Imports SqlHelpers) is a class project from above.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports SqlHelpers

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim contacts = New List(Of String) From {"May Jones", "Tim O'Brian"}
        Examples.ReadCustomersByContactType(contacts)
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Examples
    Public Shared Function ReadCustomersByContactType(pContactTitleList As List(Of String)) As DataTable

        'mHasException = False

        ' field which the WHERE IN will use
        Dim parameterPrefix = "CT.ContactTitle"

        ' Base SELECT Statement
        Dim selectStatement =
                <SQL>
            SELECT C.CustomerIdentifier ,
                   C.CompanyName ,
                   C.ContactName ,
                   C.ContactTypeIdentifier ,
                   FORMAT(C.ModifiedDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy', 'en-US') AS ModifiedDate,
                   CT.ContactTitle
            FROM   dbo.Customers AS C
            INNER JOIN dbo.ContactType AS CT ON C.ContactTypeIdentifier = CT.ContactTypeIdentifier
            WHERE <%= parameterPrefix %> IN ({0}) AND Req_ID = "R1"
            ORDER BY C.CompanyName
            </SQL>.Value

        ' Builds the SELECT statement minus values
        Dim CommandText = BuildWhereInClause(selectStatement, parameterPrefix, pContactTitleList)

        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection

            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

                cmd.CommandText = CommandText

                '
                ' Add values for command parameters
                '
                cmd.AddParamsToCommand(parameterPrefix, pContactTitleList)
                Console.WriteLine()
                Try
                    'cn.Open()

                    'dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

                Catch ex As Exception
                    'mHasException = True
                    'mLastException = ex
                End Try

            End Using
        End Using

        Return dt

    End Function
End Class
```

In the Git repository there is also a custom TextBox if needed.
[image]